# Elmah always logs two identical exceptions: any idea why?

Tags: logging, exception, elmah

I've used Elmah in a number of projects and in each of them two identical log records are generated for each and every exception. Besides the clutter and waste of space its working fine otherwise.

Has anyone seen this behavior before or have a clue where to start looking?

EDIT: {from global.asax.cs}

```
    protected void Application_Error() {
        // Use ELMAH to log the exception
        var exception = Server.GetLastError();
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        var signal = ErrorSignal.FromContext(context);
        if (signal != null) {
            signal.Raise(exception, context);
        }

        // Show custom error page if necessary
        if (!_showCustomErrorPages) return;
        if (exception is HttpRequestValidationException) {
            DisplayErrorPage("InvalidInput");
            return;
        }

        DisplayErrorPage("Error");
    }
```

this is example code I was using from the "whocanhelpme" project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the ELMAH error logging module registered twice in `Web.config`, perhaps?

It's ok to have it once in `system.web\httpModules` and once in `system.webServer\modules`, but my initial thought was that maybe you have it registered *twice* in one (or more) of these sections. Perhaps you could edit your question to include the contents of your `Web.config` file (of course, removing any sensitive information like email settings or connection strings)?

Another thought - do you have an `Application_OnError` event handler in `Global.asax`, per chance? If so, are you doing anything in there that might cause ELMAH to log the error a second time?

Comment: hmmmm, come to think of it I have been using example code from the whocanhelpme project as part of the elmah implementation and they just happen to be throwing in the Application_OnError and even have a comment to that effect... obviously this is responsible for one copy. Of course now the question would be "what were they thinking when they wrote this." I need to look at this a little closer.